# How to make default wordpress display name Username instead?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have tried a few codes in `functions.php` to force default WordPress display to be a username upon registration without luck. Here is my codes:

```
add_action('user_register', 'registration_save_displayname', 1000);
function registration_save_displayname($user_id) {
if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'])){
    $pretty_name = $_POST['user_login'];
    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'display_name'=> $pretty_name) ) ;
}
}
```

At present, WordPress creates a display name using username ( if first and last name are not available on registration form ), plus numeric number like `johnav2345`, if a username is `johnav`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your code works, because it is missing a line of `$user_nicename`.

Just in case anyone need this, here is a fully working code:

```
function set_default_display_name( $user_id ) {
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );
$name = $user_id;
$args = array(
    'ID' => $user_id,
    'display_name' => $name     // Force Display name to be a Username
);
wp_update_user( $args );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_default_display_name' );
```

Not sure, why WP won't recognise `$user_login` as a username, but with the above codes it works perfectly. WordPress seems to force display name to be switched to Username instead of User ID.

Comment: This doesn't work, it sets the username to the user_id as is clear it would from the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
function user_set_default_displayname($user_id) {

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    $args = array(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'display_name' => $user->user_nicename,
    );

    wp_update_user( $args );
}
add_action('user_register', 'user_set_default_displayname', 90);
```

Untested, but it should work.

You can change `user_nicename` with other values from `user` object: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: Very clear, works perfectly.